# Issues with commutative property of && operator

Tags: c++, arduino, embedded, logical-operators

The code below that I have been having strange issues with is meant to trim off the unused portion of an integer array, and then convert it into a string.

Ex:
`_ABC__DE______` would become `_ABC__DE`.

The problems show up when the input is filled with the default character. ("_" in the example).

`sLength` is the length of the integer array `chars`

The problematic code:

```
  int inputLength = sLength - 1;

  while (chars[inputLength] == defaultChar && inputLength >= 0) {
    inputLength--;
  }

  inputLength++;

  Serial.println("input length: " + String(inputLength));
  // (in)sanity check
  Serial.println(inputLength);
  Serial.println(String(inputLength));
  Serial.println(inputLength <= 0);
  Serial.println(0 <= 0);
  Serial.println(inputLength == 0);
  Serial.println(0 == 0);

  if (inputLength <= 0) {
    //reset cursor position
    Serial.println("index set to 0");
    index = 0;
  } else {
    output = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < inputLength; i++) {
      char c = charSet[chars[i]];
      if (c == '_') {
        c = ' ';
      }
      output += c;
    }
    done = true;
  }
```

The output when given an array filled with `defaultChar`:

```
input length: 0
0
0
0
1
0
1
```

If I'm interpreting correctly, the output means that 0 > 0 and 0 =/= 0 on even lines, but 0 <= 0 and 0 = 0 on odd lines.

---

The workaround I've come up with is replacing

```
  while (chars[inputLength] == defaultChar && inputLength >= 0) {
    inputLength--;
  }
```

with one of the following

```
  while (inputLength >= 0 && chars[inputLength] == defaultChar) {
    inputLength--;
  }
```

.

```
  while (chars[inputLength] == defaultChar) {
    inputLength--;
    if (inputLength < 0) {
      break;
    }
  }
```

which both result in an output of:

```
input length: 0
0
0
1
1
1
1
index set to 0
```

---

Why does this change the result?
As far as I knew until now, the && operator was commutative.

Is there something that I am missing that makes

`chars[inputLength] == defaultChar && inputLength >= 0`

not equal to

`inputLength >= 0 && chars[inputLength] == defaultChar`?

If It's relevant, this is being run on an 328P Arduino Nano with the old bootloader using IDE 1.8.8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`&&` is not commutative. It evaluates the left operand first and then stops if the left operand evaluated to `0`.

Your original code fails because at some point it evaluates `chars[-1]` (which causes [undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4105123/1505939) if `chars` is an array).  The alternative version does not have that problem because it performs the `>= 0` test before using `inputLength` as an array index.

Answer (score 3):

`&&` is commutative in the sense that the result of `a && b` is same as the result of `b && a`. But the built-in operator `&&` has a [short-circuiting behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_logical). This means that if the result of `a && b` can be decided by evaluating the first operand alone, the second one is not evaluated.

So when the first operand is `chars[inputLength] == defaultChar` and `inputLength` is `-1`, you enter the territory of undefined behavior which means the behavior of the program is unpredictable. But with the workarounds, you **avoid** undefined behavior because of the `inputLength >= 0`  and `inputLength < 0` checks and therefore the code works as intended.

As @PeteBecker notes: `a() && b()` is not commutative if either `a()` or `b()` has side effects.

Comment: You might mention that `a() && b()` is not commutative if `a()` or `b()` has side effects.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Thank you. Added that to the answer.